# References that start with "

Tags: bibtex

I use BibTex to manage my references. Now I have a small problem. The title of one of my references starts with `"I don't ... "`. When I generate the bibliography it looks like this:

```
""i don' ...
```

Why is the I here not in capital letters? All other of my references start with a capital letter.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: If you want to preserve the case of your letters, add braces around them: `{I Don't}` -> `I Don't` and `{I} Don't` -> `I Don't` or `I don't` depending on the style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many BibTeX bibliography styles -- including, it would appear to be the case, the one you're using -- are set to automatically lowercase all letters in an entry's `title` field (except if the letter is at the very start of the title field string) if the entry is of type `article`, `techreport`, `misc`, or `unpublished`. This lower-casing setting, however, generally doesn't apply if the entry is of, say, type `book`.

Since the title of one of your references starts with ``` ``I don't ... ``` rather than with `I don't ...`, the `I` is *not* the very first character of the title field and hence is converted to lowercase. To keep this from happening, you must surround it by braces, as in

```
title = "``{I} don't ... ''",
```